# Proof of the bias-variance decomposition in Bishop's book

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, variance, bias

[image]

I am trying to rewrite the demonstration given in Bishop's book: [Pattern Recognition and
Machine Learning (2009)](https://moodle2.units.it/pluginfile.php/24254/mod_resource/content/1/Bishop_2009_Pattern_recognition_and_machine_learning.pdf)

I reproduce the figure (page 149) in which I am unclear about the step leading from (3.39) to (3.40) and described with this judgment: *"We now take the expectation of this expression with respect to D and note that the final term will vanish, giving"*.

I ask the kindness if anyone has all the steps of this demonstration

Comment: Look at the term immediately following "$2:$" when you take expectations, you will be subtracting an expectation from itself, giving $0,$ *etc.*

Answer (score 2):

To simplify notation, assume that expectation and $\small y$ is conditioned on $\small D$: $\small y = y(x;\mathcal{D}), E=E_\mathcal{D}$. Then
$$
\small
E[(y-h(x))^2] = E[(y-E[y]+E[y] -h(x))^2] = \text{Bias}^2+\text{Variance} + 2E[y - E[y]](E[y] - h(x))
$$
Expectation is linear so $\small E[y - E[y]] = E[y] - E[y] = 0$ implying
$$
\small
E[(y-h(x))^2] = \text{Bias}^2+\text{Variance} + 2\cdot 0\cdot (E[y] - h(x)) = \text{Bias}^2+\text{Variance}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is to the prove a fact:

\begin{align*}
\int \{a - g(b)\}^2 p(b) db &= \{a - \mathbb{E}[g(b)] \}^2 + \text{var}[g(b)] \\
\end{align*}

where

- $a$ is a constant independent of $b$
- $b$ is a random variable,
- $g$ is a function of $b$,
- $p(b)$ is a distribution of $b$. It may or may not be a conditional distribution.

**The proof**:

\begin{align}
\int \{a - g(b) \}^2 p(b) db
&= \int (a - \mathbb{E}[g] + \mathbb{E}[g] - g)^2 p(b) db \\
&= \int \Big[(a - \mathbb{E}[g])^2 + 2 (a - \mathbb{E}[g])(\mathbb{E}[g] - g) + (\mathbb{E}[g] - g)^2 \Big ] p(b) db \\
&= (a - \mathbb{E}[g])^2  + \int \left[ 2 (a - \mathbb{E}[g])(\mathbb{E}[g] - g) + (\mathbb{E}[g] - g)^2 \right ] p(b) db \\
&= (a - \mathbb{E}[g])^2  + \int \left[ 2 a \mathbb{E}[g] - 2\mathbb{E}[g]^2 - 2ag + 2g\mathbb{E}[g] + \mathbb{E}[g]^2 - 2\mathbb{E}[g]g + g^2 \right] p(b) db \\
&= (a - \mathbb{E}[g])^2  + \int \left[ 2 a \mathbb{E}[g] - \mathbb{E}[g]^2 - 2ag + g^2 \right] p(b) db \\
&= (a - \mathbb{E}[g])^2  + 2 a \mathbb{E}[g] - \mathbb{E}[g]^2 - 2a\mathbb{E}[g] + \mathbb{E}[b^2] \\
&= (a - \mathbb{E}[g])^2 - \mathbb{E}[g]^2 + \mathbb{E}[g^2] \\
&= (a - \mathbb{E}[g])^2 + \text{var}[g] \\
\end{align}

Note,

- we write $g(b)$ as $g$ for clarity
- $\mathbb{E}[g(b)] = \int g(b) p(b) db $, and it is independent of $b$.
- in the last equality, by [definition of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), $\text{var}[g] = \mathbb{E}[g^2] - \mathbb{E}[g]^2$.

Applying the fact to Eq. (3.40):

- $a = h(x)= \mathbb{E}_{t|\mathbb{x}}[t]$
- $b = D$
- $g(b) = y(x; \mathcal{D})$

The derivation above used the same expansion as in Eq. (3.39), which is cluttered with symbols and more difficult to read.

The same trick is also used in proving Eq. (1.90) in PRML, but $a$, $b$, and $g$ would have different meanings in that context. I've re-derived the results with more details in the Theory part of https://nbviewer.org/github/zyxue/sutton-barto-rl-exercises/blob/master/supervised/decompose-MSE-and-demo.ipynb if you're interested.